# White margin at top of website

Tags: html, css

I have read many different problems referring to a white margin at the top of website and I haven't found an answer to help.

http://codepen.io/WikiWookie/pen/DijrI

Here is my code.  I've just started to learn html/css and I'm trying to make a navigation like bootstrap's.  I'm trying to do it from scratch, so I can learn more stuff

Oh yeah, I've tried to mess with some margin elements, but to no avail.  Thanks guys!

Comment: The white space is a product of "[margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)".

Comment: As a beginner —  use a CSS reset.

Comment: Put the code here please

Comment: @ScottSimpson I did use a css reset with my normalize.css file

Comment: Normalize.css is great to use -- but it is not a reset. See the difference between: http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ and normalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<ul>` margin is "bleeding" through your header and creating the white space. Either set:

```
header ul {margin-top: 0;}
```

Or

```
header nav {overflow: hidden;}
```

Or similar clearfix to contain margin within header.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I didn't think the UL would have a default margin after I used normalize.css.

Answer (score 2):

Remove margins from ul tag

```
ul{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGzjq

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, when you are using codepen, you do not put in any code in the html area except for what goes between your body tags. Codepen is set up to automatically link to your css & javascript files.

As far as having the nav bar positioned at the very top, left corner of your site, you can absolutely position the element(s) like I've shown below.

```
header nav
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Remember, if you absolutely position the nav bar, you need to change the positioning of the next element that follows. A good way to learn about positioning is to use the developer tools in the browser and select the area you are interested in learning about. You will be able to see all the html & css to reveal how the developer of the site built their pages. Hope this helps. Here are a couple of links that helped me when I was first starting to code.

[CSS Tricks: Absolute Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

[Explaining CSS Positioning](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm)